# Was "Sleep No More" the first Doctor Who episode without the theme music and credits?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor Who episode "Sleep No More," season nine, episode nine, only had a brief highlight of the words "Doctor Who" on the screen, not the usual theme music and crazy opening title-sequence. Is this the first time that's been done on either the new (2005) series or the old (1963) series? I can't remember an instance right now, but that doesn't mean there haven't been any... Can any one name an earlier episode that forgoes the credits/theme? (At least one and the question's answered. *Not after a list..*.)

Comment: Are you just looking for opening credits? The final episode of Earthshock (5th Doctor) rolled the end credits in silence over a static backdrop. The reason why involves spoilers so I won't mention in a comment.

Comment: I understand the reason for that silence, but I am only asking about opening credits here as I'm asking about the newest episode.

Comment: No problem... one day somebody will ask a classic who question and it will be my time to shine :)

Comment: You can ask a question and answer it. That's totally legit. This is a database of answered questions being built. No shame in it, mate.

Comment: Why no theme music?   Is this a dumb question?   I'm just not familiar.

Comment: @ThePopMachine There was no theme music for this episode in keeping with the "found footage" aspect. Wouldn't make sense to have credits after someone tells you you're going to see helmet-camera and CCV. Smart idea, I think. If you're asking about the Earthshock episode raze brought up, that was an episode-centric homage.

Comment: I maintain that leaving out the theme song means that the episode is not canon, but I don't really expect anyone to agree with me. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, *Sleep No More* was the first.

See e.g. [this article](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-11-14/doctor-who-opening-titles-dropped-for-first-time-ever) entitled "Doctor Who Opening Titles Dropped For First Time Ever".

While "Sleep No More" is the first proper **season episode** to do this, it's not the first televised *Doctor Who* story to skimp on the titles, nor the most severe: while "Sleep No More" at least flashes the episode title in the end credits, the 2005 *Children In Need* special doesn't tell us its title at all. (And the experimental Big Finish audio story "LIVE 34" doesn't have that series' normal title or credit elements either.)

Comment: Man, that's an ugly game-show-looking, low-res image... When I clicked thru to your linked article I actually thought to myself, "at least *that's* not on the SE page." *And now it is.* Still, I'm just glad to have my question answered. I vote yes for you and the answer and vote no for the image. **: P**

Comment: @MeatTrademark I can remove it again if you *really* want :-)

Comment: Now I *miss* it. It was like a low-rent Doctor Who-based Family Fued screencap. Dang. Just ain't no pleasin' me... **;)**